# magento 2 select province to refresh shipping method in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, checkout-page

**Magento checkout pages select province to refresh shipping method in Magento 2.help me**

Comment: What you want here? Write more details.

Comment: select
 https://prnt.sc/oolc55
to refresh shipping method
https://prnt.sc/oold5y